# Loading texture using SOILs OGL function and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

I have a function to load a texture from a JPEG image using SOIL.

So far I have been loading the texture with the `SOIL_load_image()` function and then supplying the image to OpenGL using `glTexImage2D` (see code below). However! My textures is upside down, so I wanted to use the `SOIL_load_OGL_texture()` instead and supply the `SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y` in order to flip the images. My problem is though, that I get an unhandled exception at the `SOIL_load_OGL_texture()` function.

The code is almost a copy paste from the documentation, so I don’t understand why this error occurs?

(NOTE: I could invert the textures in my vertex shader, but I would like to use SOIL.)

**The old way**

```
int width;
int height;

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

image = SOIL_load_image(filename, &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);

if (image == NULL) {
    std::cout << "An error occurred while loading image." << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
std::cout << "Loaded first texture image" << std::endl;

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);
```

**What I am trying now**

```
GLuint image;

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

image = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
        filename,
        SOIL_LOAD_RGB,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
    );

if (image == 0)
    cerr << "SOIL loading error: '" << SOIL_last_result() << "' (" << "res_texture.png" << ")" << endl;
```

**And the error**

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0F5427FF (msvcr110d.dll) in AnotherTutorial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Comment: In the `SOIL_load_OGL_texture()` version why are you (apparently) throwing away the new texture object (`image`)?

Comment: How am I throwing it away? With the SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID flag, or?

Comment: Well, you don't seem to be assigning `image` to `textures[0]` or `glBindTexture()`ing it.

Comment: Why do you need the `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0])` before the image loading?

Comment: @genpfault Perhaps I don't completely understand the SOIL_load_OGL_texture; I thought that it loaded a texture directly into OpenGL, and I therefore did not need to call something like glTexImage2D?

Comment: @Grimmy I load three images in total, so I call the function three times (textures[0], textures[1], textures[2]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no answer to using SOIL, so i'll post my solution:

In the vertex shader I do:

```
Texcoord = vec2(texcoord.x, 1.0-texcoord.y);
gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4( position, 1.0 );
```

The 1.0-texcoord.y inverts the y-axis of the image. Not as clean a solution, but it works.

Comment: I thought you're having a problem with the RT error occurring not flipping upside down the texture?

Answer (score 1):

```
void loadTexture(GLuint* texture, char* path){
    *texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(filename,
                                     SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
                                     SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
                                     SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA
                                    );
    if(*textre == NULL){
        printf("[Texture loader] \"%s\" failed to load!\n", filename);
    }
}

void drawTexturedRect(int x, int y, int w, int h, GLuint texture){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor3f(255,255,255);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex2f(x+w,y);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glVertex2f(x,y+h);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex2f(x+w,y+h);
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glVertex2f(x,y+h);
    glEnd();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

And then you can do:

```
// At initialization
GLuint texture;
loadTexture(&texture, "filename.png");

// Drawing part
drawTexturedRect(25,25,256,256,texture);
```

This is what I personally use, and it works perfectly. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 combined with SDL and SOIL.

Answer (score 0):

`SOIL_load_image` will return `unsigned char*` yes, array holding your image data.

Then you will normally feed this data to `gl` using `glGenerateTextures`, assign texture IDs, calling `glTexImage2D`.

`SOIL_load_OGL_texture` returns a texture id, so you could do this instead:

```
texture[0] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(...)
```

if your goal is to load textures 0,1,2.

As for invert y, the easiest and weight free solution is to flip the texture coordinates in `glTexCoord`, but it depends on what you are doing. If you are loading resources as a one time only operation or like, it can’t hurt, except some startup time probably not worth mentioning. But if you’re loading resources dynamically through the main loop when needed, then invert y flag (and about any flag), can hurt performance because of additional processing throughout your entire program.

One big advantage to using `SOIL_load_image` is that you can retrieve width, height and channel number from the original image which `SOIL_load_OGL_texture` doesn’t provide.

If it helps, `SOIL_load_OGL_texture` would crash after a while when loading RGB images as RGB but worked fine all the way with `SOIL_LOAD_RGBA`, that could be a fix to your problem.

I still find it easier with `SOIL_load_image`. I hope any of this helps. Also check the SOIL source code that ships with soil to see what’s going on.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use capital letters at sentence start and Markdown formatting for function names and other code snippets. This greatly improves the readability of the text. See [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in the command

```
SOIL_load_image(filename, &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
```

the 0 (NULL) you are passing is a pointer to the channels set by the library, so, of course, when the library tries to access it you have:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0F5427FF (msvcr110d.dll) in
>   AnotherTutorial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x00000000

Try declaring a variable and using it:

```
int channels;
SOIL_load_image(filename, &width, &height, &channels, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solution above works for me.
I have same problem just now, like the following one:

```
SOIL_load_OGL_texture Unhandled exception at xxxxxx (msvcr120d.dll)
```

After reading solution at http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-10281.html, 
i changed my path from "relative path" to "absolute path".

BTW, And since I am Chinese, i need to make sure that the path is ALL ENGLISH without non-ascii characters.

For example:

I change my code from

```
SOIL_load_OGL_texture("my_texture.bmp",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA
        );
```

to

```
SOIL_load_OGL_texture("D:\temp_20160926\ConsoleApplication20\ConsoleApplication19\my_texture.bmp",
        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_MULTIPLY_ALPHA
        );
```

And it solve my problem perfectly.

I think this is a bug/restriction in SOIL. But you can avoid this by specific the absolute path like i do here.

Hope it can help you too.